# Entering HALT mode with master interrupt enabled but no Interrupt Enable (0xFF0F = 0)?

Tags: interrupt, emulation, device-emulation, halt, gameboy

According to [Gameboy Programming Manual](http://chrisantonellis.com/files/gameboy/gb-programming-manual.pdf),

> HALT mode is canceled by the following events, which have the starting addresses indicated.
>
> 1. A LOW signal to the /RESET terminal Starting address: 0x0000
> 2. The interrupt-enable flag and its corresponding interrupt request flag are set
>
>    - IME = 0 (Interrupt Master Enable flag disabled)
>        Starting address: address following that of the HALT instruction
>    - IME = 1 (Interrupt Master Enable flag enabled)
>        Starting address: each interrupt starting address

Assume a program enters `HALT` mode with Interrupt Master Enable flag enabled `IME = 1` and Interrupt Enable disabled for any interrupt `0xFF0F = 0`, what would happen? What is the expected behaviour on the actual Gameboy device?

Comment: By the way, if you like emulation and you think that questions like this one would be more suitable for a separate stack exchange site, please take a look at two proposals on Area 51 [Emulation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79736/emulation) and [Retrocomputing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74814/retrocomputing).

Comment: Does the [current answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30717825/3991344) fit your needs?

Comment: @pokechu22 no, it doesn't.

Comment: The CPU will halt forever, as the answer states, that's it. If that's not the answer then edit your question to better reflect what you actually want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question right, but anyway:
According to the cited manual, the `IE` (interrupt enable) register, address `FFFF`, determines which one of the 5 interrupt types are enabled. Only those set to `1` will be accepted if `IME` (interrupt master enable) ist set to `1`.
The `IF` (interrupt flags) register, address `FF0F`, provides merely information which interrupts are requested.
So, if a program is in the `HALT` state with `IME` = `1`, any interrupt is accepted that is enabled in `IE`. Of course, somebody had to generate the interrupt(s) which would be indicated by a (or more) 1 in the `IF` register.

EDIT:

Maybe this answers your question now:
If the program enters HALT mode, Interrupt Master Enable is enabled (IME = 1), but all specific interrupt types are disabled (IE = 0), no interrupt will be accepted, and HALT mode is not left. This is the expected behavior on the device.

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answer, however this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Could you please tell me, why not?

Comment: Sorry @Reinhard Männer I had not seen your edit. Thank you!